# How to properly set the name of the BEM class for different card designs

Tags: css, class, frontend, classname, bem

Let's imagine that the task before us is to develop 50+ unique types of cards, headers, footers, etc.

It will be okay if I name the card types like this:
card-23, card-24

Or is there a better solution?

It scares me to think that all nested elements will have the prefix card-23__title, card-24__title because in fact they may be the same, and at the same time I want to be able to control a particular element separately without harming other types of cards.

Comment: You could use classes like `.card__header`, `.card__footer` etc. for common style and then use specific classes with the modifiers to assign specific style, e.g. `.card__title--23` or `.card__footer--31` defined later on the cascade.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.