# I need help, my first time using BEM, is this correct?

Tags: html, css, bem

This is my first time trying to use BEM and I'm not sure if I've done it correctly. Is there anything i need to change??

```
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <main class="main">
            <div class="main__content content">
                <div class="content__item content1">
                    <div class="content1__cirkel">
                        <img class="content1__image" src="bilder/1545876271475.jpg" alt="Saigon">
                    </div>

                    <div class="content1-info">
                        <p class="content__text">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has
                            been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="content__item content2">
                    <div class="content2__cirkel">
                        <img class="content2__image" src="bilder/21336448-81d8-4643-a1b9-1545d08172de.jpg" alt="Ha Long Bay">
                    </div>

                    <div class="content2-info">
                        <p class="content__text">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has
                            been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="content__item content3">
                    <div class="content3__cirkel">
                        <img class="content3__image" src="bilder/big-hand-ang-golden-bridge.jpg" alt="Hand Bridge">
                    </div>

                    <div class="content3-info">
                        <p class="content__text">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has
                            been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </main>
    </div>
</body>
```

I've tried reading about it and trying to tell myself if I've done it correctly but I would like a proffesional to do it aswell.

Comment: my initial thought was to remove "content" from "main__content" and replace "content__item and content1,2,3" with just "card"?

Answer (score 0):

1. Use double hyphens to separate block and element names
2. Make block names more descriptive, e.g. it's not clear what is **content**, but **card** or **article** would be nicer to use
3. Names should be consistent, don't use **content1, content2, content3** and so on.

```html
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <main class="main">
      <div class="main__content content">
        <div class="content__item card">
          <div class="card__circle">
            <img class="card__image" src="bilder/1545876271475.jpg" alt="Saigon">
          </div>

          <div class="card__info">
            <p class="card__text">
              Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="content__item card">
          <div class="card__circle">
            <img class="card__image" src="bilder/21336448-81d8-4643-a1b9-1545d08172de.jpg" alt="Ha Long Bay">
          </div>

          <div class="card__info">
            <p class="card__text">
              Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="content__item card">
          <div class="card__circle">
            <img class="card__image" src="bilder/big-hand-ang-golden-bridge.jpg" alt="Hand Bridge">
          </div>

          <div class="card__info">
            <p class="card__text">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I want to have the circle in the first card to float left whilst the last cards circle to float right? Should I add in the "card__cirkel" another class "card__cirkel--first"

Comment: Is the content_item even necessary since if iI wanna target all of them I could just write "card". And how do I specifically target a card since they are all 3 unique cards.

Comment: Depending on your design, you can leave only "card" class if it is enough for styling. To target a separate card you can use modifiers, like "card--red", "card--large". Or there is another option to use CSS pseudo selectors.

Comment: The same is for circles, you can add modifiers like "card__circle--left" or use CSS pseudo selectors if there will be only 3 cards.

Comment: Is it not ok to then switchout "content__item" to "card--1" "card--2" I saw this source https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74853888/how-to-properly-set-the-name-of-the-bem-class-for-different-card-designs

Comment: Modifiers should be meaningful, using indexes as modifiers don't provide any meaningful information about the component or styles.

Comment: How would you target the first card then if we don't use index and pseudo selectors?

Comment: Depending on how the styles of the first card will differ from other cards. Is it has another background color, size, or something else?

Comment: no they all look the same, its just that when the site is in mobile form I want it to appear in the middle card whilst on desktop I want It to appear as the first card

Comment: Then "card-first" will be good for such case :)